# How to get specific data from large json object into Jade mixin

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

This is the json from my sever:

`data = {"id":393, "state":"mississippi", "lat":null, "lng":null, "title":"someTitle", "country":null};`

I then pass that through a Jade temple like so: `res.render('editUpload', {fromServer:data});`

Then in my Jade template I have this:

```
var data = !{fromServer};
console.log(data.address);
```

Which correctly prints mississippi

However, I'm trying to get my mixins to use that data

Mixin:

```
mixin textBoxMixin(name, label, value)
    div(style="display:flex; width:100%;")
        span.label #{label}
        input(type="text", name="#{name}", value="#{value}")
```

Then I use that like this:

```
+textBoxMixin("title", "Title", fromServer)
```

which fills in the text box with the entire json "{"id":393, "state":"mississippi", "lat":null, "lng":null, "title":"someTitle", "country":null}" so I go and try this:

```
+textBoxMixin("title", "Title", fromServer.title)
```

it prints "undefined".

**How do I get this mixin to accept what should just be `fromServer.title`?**

I've tried JSON.stringify(fromServer), data.address (which obviously doesn't work because data is undefined during the rendering of the page). I know that I could go back to my server and parse out all the json there and pass each item as an individual item, but that would be a giant pain since my json is actually much larger than what I've posted here.

> The problem was that I was sending the json from the route.js file to the template after having passed it through `JSON.stringify()`, this let me use `var data = !{fromServer};` in the page's scripts, but Jade couldn't parse the String. So now I'm doing this in the route so that I have both the json available for templating and the String for JavaScript:

```
    data = rows[0][0];
    stringFromServer = JSON.stringify(rows[0][0]);
    res.render('editUpload', {fromServer:data, stringFromServer:stringFromServer, username: req.session.user});
```

Comment: first of all, this is how you should be printing mississipi to your file: Line 1: `- var data = fromServer`. Line 2: `= data.state`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference parameters in your mixin definition, you pass them exactly as if it were normal pug code, without quotes and braces.

```
mixin textBoxMixin(name, label, value)
  div(style="display:flex; width:100%;")
    span.label= label
    input(type="text", name=name, value=value)

+textBoxMixin("title", "Title", fromServer.title)
```

Here's what renders:

[image: rendering from mixin]

Also, Jade is now Pug, and I know you know that since you tagged Pug in this question, you should start referencing it as Pug :).

Comment: That just gives me a textBox with value = undefined

Comment: hmm.. I just uploaded what renders for me. I would have to see your entire pug file.

Comment: Here's the latest on github: https://github.com/glenpierce/epistemology/tree/glen

Comment: Link directly to the .jade file https://github.com/glenpierce/epistemology/blob/glen/views/editUpload.jade

Comment: I cloned your repo and plugged in a test file. My code still works. The only difference is that the data I'm passing is a json object and what you're passing is a string. Can you pass it as a json? otherwise, you need to do a `JSON.parse()` inside the jade template, which I don't recommend.

Comment: Also, I see most of your routes require a connection to a MySQL instance. I would suggest you add a middleware to all those routes so you don't have to repeat the same code everywhere; it would make your files much smaller and easier to read.